# How can we disable default browser style properties for elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having issue in design on forms and links on a page I created because of the browser style properties. How can I disable it so that no elements in my html page gets affected by the browsers' default style property?

All solutions are welcome. I am using php for development. So all solutions with css, javascript, php etc are welcomed.

Comment: [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Comment: Isn't there any single line code/statement available for disabling the entire browser default style?

Comment: There is: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css">`

Comment: @AeJey If you could disable them, how should any element be displayed if it had no style?

Comment: If there was something else, all those CSS reset stylesheets probably wouldn't exist :)

Comment: [This page](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/using-a-custom-stylesheet-in-a-web-browser/) tells about the location of the default css style files for chrome and firefox. as i understand the author you may swap them with a customized file which might be a viable workaround for programmatic disabling.

Comment: @collapsar These changes will only affect to your browser, you cannot change a file via JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *disable* browser default style sheets, just *override* them by setting properties to specific values. It is common to confuse the two.

This is a decision by browser vendors. They could give a page (scripts on a page) access to the browser’s stylesheet allowing it or parts thereof to be disabled. But they haven’t done that.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe put `!important` behind the css you want to overwrite the default style properties?

maybe this solves your solution?

Comment: I know that. That is not what I was asking. I want to disable the entire default style settings of browsers (firefox, chrome etc.) by inserting some piece of code on the page.

Comment: then I can't help you with your problem, sorry.

Comment: It's okay mate. What I am looking for is 
"There are php codes available for disabling browser cache-ing. Can we disable style properties too like that using some code?"

Answer (score 1):

There must be a default style for all elements, so you cannot just disable them.
The usual way to handle this issue is adding your desired defaults in a base CSS file, overwriting the browser's defaults.

As @link commented, http://www.cssreset.com/ provides several default styles to be applied as base in your pages.

Comment: There are php codes available for disabling browser cache-ing. Can we disable style properties too like that using some code?

Comment: No, disabling cache has nothing to do with this: you can tell a browser to not cache your data, forcing it to download all every time the page is requested, but default styles are given by the browser itself

Answer (score 1):

Please use normalize css :

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

It'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override browser's default stylesheet. You can do it many ways-

- Manually define every elements style
- Use any reset.css (You can find many)
- Use a basic html startup tamplate, which covers everything you need. You can find one [here](http://www.initializr.com/), It has many options to choose from.

Hope you will love it :-)

Comment: There are php codes available for disabling browser cache-ing. Can we disable style properties too like that using some code?

Comment: May be there are some code. But I don't know about any. I prefer [Initilizr](http://www.initializr.com/). It provides some pretty good assets to start working with.